# Can't open .exe file on CD because it's read only

Tags: wine, printing, cd, executable, read-only

So I have this software CD for my Canon MX420 printer that I've been trying to install onto my computer. However, when I run the .exe setup file, it says I need to run the program as an administrator. Then, after adding the open-as-administrator Nautilus script, I can't change the .exe to open as an executable because it says the file system is read-only. I can't access my printer without this software CD, and I'm not sure how else I could run the setup to get the necessary files.

Comment: What? You are trying to use the Windows drivers for linux use? I smell problems there. If you really need drivers for Linux, look for them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The linux drivers seems to be available on the european site of canon.

http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MX_series/PIXMA_MX420.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd been trying to do that, but I'd been using the wrong repository, and your comment made me retrace my steps. My printer's working fine now!